# how to remove border from embed video (squarespace)

Tags: css, video, squarespace, video-embedding

I'm using following code for to embed video, play without any control and auto play and loop. And its working fine, but the issue is its automatically creating a border on the video.

```
<video width="1000" height="450" loop autoplay="autoplay" />
 <source src="/s/m31.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
```

And i have tried `<param name="border" value="off">`

But still border into the video. Pl anyone help how to remove the border line.

Comment: Have you tried a value of `0` or `false` for the border param?

Comment: Could you upload this on jsfiddle or something so that we can mess around with it?

Comment: @zgood yea, tried 0 and false

Comment: @Gustaf I have video in mp4 format and i have uploaded into my site and its local link like /s/movie.mp4. I don't know jsfiddle.

Comment: Link your site, please @user3766722

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood, anyway I think you could play a little bit with CSS. I made a container smaller than the video to hide black "borders" in this example http://jsfiddle.net/ungarida/w9qkv2oc/
http://jsfiddle.net/ungarida/w9qkv2oc/2/

```
html, body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: #efefef;
}
#container {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   height: 300px;
   width: 580px;
   background-color: white;
   display: block;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
}

video {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   width: 600px;
   position: absolute;
   top: -40px;
   left: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ungarida, its works, but can't remove left side border.

Comment: I made a v2 with your video, you have just to do some mathematics with your preferences in terms of width and height.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty fix:

```
video{
    left: -1px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the border is part of the video itself, so either clean up the video itself, or resort to this.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not a border, try with outline.

`video{
    outline: 0px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Meak video size bigger than container and hide overflow

```
.container{
  width: 60rem;
  height: 28rem;
  overflow: hidden;

  position: relative;
  video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-53%, -50%);
    width: 60rem;
    height: 42rem;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).